# TableView and Collection view Layout in same view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, layout, uicollectionview

I have two `UIViewControllers`, When I click on a button of first `UIViewController` then tableView(Of Second UIViewController)  should open, and when I click on another button of First `UIViewController` then Collection view(Of Second UIViewController) should open.

I mean When Table View will open Collection view will be hidden and Vice versa, both I want in a single View controller.
In image you can see that TableView open with images, but when I will click on first cell the collection view should open in same layout.I mean it has to show like this.

I am new in UI.
So How can I implement the UI.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: First: do you have any code that you tried? Second: I suggest to let it a single collection view instead of adding both table view and another collection view, all you have to do is to change the cell for the collection view...

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I have to implement so I am thinking to get idea.

Comment: I have to show only one at a time either  collection  view or Table view using
only one View Controller.

Comment: Pass the respective tag on Button Click.. And in `viewDidLoad` (or `viewDidAppear`) method of second view check which button clicked.

Comment: I know this @Piyush.
I am asking for UI Prospective.
Thanks

Comment: yes @kishor0011 you need to hide and show as per your requirement.

Comment: Yes Piyush but my question is table view and collection. How can I create a UI for a single View controller. I am new in UI.

Comment: @kishor0011 add Screenshot of your requirement

Comment: Please check my updated question.
Thanks

Comment: @kishor0011 my suggestion is use two ViewController if you can..

Comment: but how can we give two SWReveal right view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking question.

I am assuming you are doing in this way:

First put a global Bool Variable called: flagIsShowTableView

Now on your FirstViewController when you click on buttonTable for table:

you have to set Bool:   `flagIsShowTableView = true`

Now when you click on buttonCollection:

you have to set Bool:   `flagIsShowTableView = false`

Now on SecondViewController:

in ViewWillAppear: you have to manage in this way:

```
if(flagIsShowTableView) {
  tblView.hidden = false
  colView.hidden = true
} else {
  colView.hidden = false
  tblView.hidden = true
}
```

I am sure that you have set and manage all the delegate and datasources methods.

Comment: Yeah this logic is correct , But I am asking for UI Implement.

Comment: Ok,....put your UITableView and UICollectionView in the single UIViewController. make proper outlets and connections.
Drag your both objects in your UIViewController.

Comment: Ok after that?
Thanks

Comment: Once you have put these objects in your controller then implement their delegate and datasources methods. Now initially set hidden both views so you don't get any trouble.

Comment: Ok and after that?

Comment: Now you are calling webservices, If you are showing same data in both table and collection then pass array count in NumberOfRowsInSection for table and collection method.

Comment: Yeah but I have to change frame also ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129863/discussion-between-gourav-joshi-and-kishor0011).